# Error while loading the keras model h5, need to convert model from tf.keras to keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

Keras model h5 is stored/saved using tensorflow.keras.model and this is creating problems while loading the model in keras 2.2.4 (without tensorflow backend using other backend framework). Please can you suggest me way to convert this tf.keras h5 to Keras loadable version.

```
    model = load_model("/home/Documents/explorePrj/Segmentation/models/model.h5", compile=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/saving.py", line 419, in load_model
    model = _deserialize_model(f, custom_objects, compile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/saving.py", line 225, in _deserialize_model
    model = model_from_config(model_config, custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/saving.py", line 458, in model_from_config
    return deserialize(config, custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/layers/__init__.py", line 55, in deserialize
    printable_module_name='layer')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/utils/generic_utils.py", line 145, in deserialize_keras_object
    list(custom_objects.items())))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/network.py", line 1022, in from_config
    process_layer(layer_data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/network.py", line 1008, in process_layer
    custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/layers/__init__.py", line 55, in deserialize
    printable_module_name='layer')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/utils/generic_utils.py", line 147, in deserialize_keras_object
    return cls.from_config(config['config'])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 1109, in from_config
    return cls(**config)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ragged'
```

Comment: Do you have any custom loss or custom metrics? I've had a similar problem where custom losses and metrics need to be defined in the file that is loading the h5 file

Comment: Did you try with importing "load_model()" from tf.keras.models  instead of keras?